# Cover a vector space with its subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume we have an $N$ dimension vector space $V$ with sub spaces $W_1,...,W_k$ 
which every one of them have dimension $M$. I am looking for a properties that should be hold between these sub spaces that would result in the following statement:
Span of any $L$ number of sub spaces $(L < k)$, for example $span(W_1,...,W_L)$, be equal to $V$.
I really appreciate any opinions you may have.